# Why is it printing the address when the example I am using doesn't print the address?

Tags: python

I want to return the values of the chain map both as is and then in reverse order.

The example I used which runs appropriately in git bash is from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chainmap-in-python .

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  

from collections import ChainMap  

def chainMap():  

  d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}  

  d2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}  

  d3 = {'c': 5, 'd': 6}  

  c = ChainMap(d1, d2, d3)  

  r = c  

  r.maps = reversed(c.maps)  

  return c.maps
```

What I want is for the return statement to include a string saying "this is the chain map: [chainmap] and this is the chain map in reverse: [chainmap in reverse]". But trying to use the + operator causes an error. And when I do just one of them it gives me its memory address.

I've played around with this in many different ways. Sometimes I get the original chainMap to display as I want but never the reverse. It's confusing especially since in the example case they have a print statement that has the chain with the maps attribute so how come in that context that doesn't print as an address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r = c` doesn't mean "make a copy of c and assign it to r", it means "make r another name for the object that c is already a name for". So when you make an alteration to r, you're also making an alteration for c, because they're just different names for the same object. You can use `copy.deepcopy()` to get around this.

`reversed()` returns an iterator, not a list. You can turn the iterator into a list by wrapping it in list(): `r.maps = list(reversed(r.maps))`.